# Relaxing GDS content security policy

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to develop a visualization that relies on user-specific external graphics which are necessarily loaded from a remote source, but blocked by GDS's content security policy headers.

I'm looking for a way to stay within the CSP but still get the functionality I need. Are any of these things possible...?

1. Could I fetch graphical resources via a data source? (In which case I could build a custom data source connector that fetches the images and then feed those as a value into the visualization.)
2. Is there a valid way to load external resources of any type without violating the CSP?
3. Google's documentation suggests that they will relax their content security policy "in some cases." Is there an avenue to provide that?

Anyone who's managed to work around this, I'd appreciate some help figuring it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't make requests, but you can potentially render an svg/canvas image based on the data, so if you had the svg string of an icon as part of the datasource, you could render that.
   2&3. There is no current way to make external requests without violating the CSP.